# uiGmapgoogle-maps marker not showing

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map set up on my page and want to place a marker on it. I just need one marker where the coords are the center of the map, but somehow my marker is not showing (the map loads, zooms and centers correctly).

There is no error in the console, so I have no idea what's wrong.

here's my html:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
            <ui-gmap-marker ng-model="marker" idkey="0" coords="'coords'"></ui-gmap-markers>
        </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

and my controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ZICApp')
    .controller('LandingController', function ($scope) {
        // google map settings
        $scope.map = { 
            center: { latitude: 46.042356, longitude: 14.487859 },
            zoom: 16 
        };

        // google map marker settings
        $scope.marker = [
        {
        id: 0,
        coords: {
            latitude: 46.042356,
            longitude: 14.487859
            }
        }
        ];
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to change my html `(model to models, and idkey="0" to idKey="idKey")`, so the html marker tag now looks like this:

```
<ui-gmap-markers models="marker" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" idKey="'idKey'"></ui-gmap-markers>
```

I also changed the id key in my controller to 1:

```
$scope.marker = [
{
    idKey: 1,
    latitude: 46.042356,
    longitude: 14.487859
}
];
```

marker is now displaying correctly.